# Opentok when disabled video shows web cam led on

Tags: javascript, opentok

I am using Opentok in a JS website and I am seeing the webcam led turn on even I have set off the video conference. When I make the call I am not able to see the other user but this turn on led is really annoying.

This is what I am doing for using voice only:

```
var pubOptions = {publishAudio:true, publishVideo:false};
```

// Initialize a Publisher, and place it into the element with id="publisher"

```
var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, 'publisher',pubOptions);
```

Am I missing something in order to make a proper voice only call?

Thanks

Comment: Also you are using a legacy version of `initPublisher`. You should do this instead:

`var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', pubOptions);`

(Assuming there is an element on the page with the ID `publisher`)

Comment: thanks for the info! regarding this change I have a `publisher` element in the page but for some reason the video element is attached to the end of the html. If I use the legacy configuration it is attached to the `publisher` div

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine, as long as the element is attached to the page BEFORE `initPublisher` is called. If you're certain the element exists then you can select the element yourself and provide it to `initPublisher`, like this: `var el = document.querySelector('#publisher'); var publisher = OT.initPublisher(el, {videoSource: null});`. I recommend you avoid the legacy method signature.

Comment: I've confirmed the reason the legacy version works for you is because you are calling `initPublisher` before the element has loaded, probably because the `<script>` tag is placed before the publisher in the HTML. You should either move your Javascript to below the publisher element or use an event listener to run your Javascript once the page has loaded.

Comment: Yes! it was due to the init publisher before loading the page...I just moved it to do int on window.onload and it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want video at all during the call then you will want to use the `videoSource` property instead of the `publishVideo` property.

`publishVideo` is just for the initial state of the publisher, but it still requests access to the camera in case you later call `publisher.publishVideo(true)`.

If you set `videoSource` to null then it does not request access to the camera.

```
var pubOptions = {videoSource: null};
```

> If you set this property to null or false, the browser does not request access to the camera, and no video is published. In a voice-only call, set this property to null or false for each Publisher.

From: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher